# Corona touch event?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

How do I register the whole display screen as an event listener?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create main.lua and add this.

```
function drawLine( event )
  if(event.phase == "ended") then
    line = display.newLine(event.xStart, event.yStart, event.x, event.y)
    line:setColor(255,0,0)
    line.width = 5
  end
end
Runtime:addEventListener("touch", drawLine)
```

Make sure to check out this site of course http://developer.anscamobile.com/resources/docs

Answer (score 0):

add the event listener to Runtime